# python Obspy st.plot()

Tags: python

Tengo una consulta sobre un codigo que estoy ejectuando sobre un `archivo.mseed`:

**codigo:**

```
from obspy import read
st=read('weather.mseed')
tr=st[0]
print (tr.stats)
st.plot()
```

Esto llama a un `archivo.mseed` y lo plotea, el problema es que el archivo `weather.mseed` es un archivo que transforme de .txt a .mseed con un codigo que encontre en la documentacion de obspy: http://docs.obspy.org/tutorial/code_snippets/anything_to_miniseed.html en este caso el código del enlace transforma una cadena de texto. Yo transforme un `archivo.txt`. para el código del enlace"anything_to_miniseed.html" tampoco me funciona y me entrega el mismo error:

```
File "leermseed.py", line 10, in <module>
    st.plot()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/obspy/core/stream.py", line 1146, in plot
    return waveform.plot_waveform(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/obspy/imaging/waveform.py", line 278, in plot_waveform
    self.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/obspy/imaging/waveform.py", line 398, in plot
    self.__plot_straight(stream_new[_i], ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/obspy/imaging/waveform.py", line 702, in __plot_straight
    trace.data = np.require(trace.data, np.float64) * trace.stats.calib
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 690, in require
    return asanyarray(a, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 544, in asanyarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: [
```

**Nota**: Quizás el archivo `txt` al pasarlo a `.mseed` no tiene el mismo formato que un verdadero `.mseed`?  porque al ejecutar estos ejercicios entregados en la documentación de `obspy` si me muestra la imagen y la onda del sismo.

http://docs.obspy.org/tutorial/code_snippets/reading_seismograms.html

Codigo con el que transformo el .txt a .mseed :

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from obspy import UTCDateTime, read, Trace, Stream

salida = []

with open('/home/pi/Desktop/lecturas4.txt', 'r') as f:

    lista = [linea.split() for linea in f]    

weather ="".join(str(x) for x in lista)


data = np.fromstring(weather, dtype='|S1')


stats = {'network': 'BW', 'station': 'RJOB', 'location': '',
         'channel': 'WLZ', 'npts': len(data), 'sampling_rate': 0.1,
         'mseed': {'dataquality': 'D'}}

stats['starttime'] = UTCDateTime()

st = Stream([Trace(data=data, header=stats)])

st.write("weather.mseed", format='MSEED', encoding=0, reclen=256)


st1 = read("weather.mseed")

print(st1[0].data.tostring())
```

---

Si le saco la linea donde dice `weather ="".join(str(x) for x in lista)` sale el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convertirArray.py", line 14, in <module>

    data = np.fromstring(lista, dtype='|S1')

TypeError: fromstring() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not list
```

Comment: De prerefencia que el codigo o errores sea siempre en texto es facil de entender y leer

Comment: editado y subido.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el código con el que transformas el archivo txt en mseed? Tiene pinta de que el error esté ahi.

Comment: listo lo añadi alfinal del post.. eran muchos caracteres para responderte por aca, saludos